# How to Avoid Duplicate Data

Tags: python, text

```
while True:
    if bbs_number > lately_number():
        sys.stdout = open('date.txt','a')
        bbs_lists = range(highest_number() +1, bbs_number +1)
        for item in bbs_lists:
            url_number = "url" + str(item)
            try:
                result = requests.get(url_number)
                bs_number = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "lxml")
                float_box = bs_number.find("div", {"class": "float_box"})
                parameter_script = float_box
                print("bs_obj()")
            except AttributeError as e:
                print("error")
    with open('lately_number.txt', 'w') as f_last:
        f_last.write(str(bbs_number))
```

Using the while statement above does not cause an error, but duplicate data will be output to `date.txt`.
I want to modify in the early stages of setting the `range` value, rather than removing duplicates in the later stages of typing in `date.txt`.

One possibility is that the existing `lately_number()` will output a duplicate `range` to `date.txt`, because sometimes it is not possible to enter the value correctly in the writing process of `lately_number.txt`.

I would be grateful if you can help me with a better function expression to add or replace.

Comment: If you show us your code we can tell you where to improve

Comment: No need to upload the code, you just include in your question

Comment: instead of modifying `sys.stdout`, use `f = open('date.txt', 'a')` and use print statements as `print('whatever', file=f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to read the date.txt into a set. Then, you can check the set to see if the date is already in there, and if it isn't, write the date to the date.txt file.

E.G.

```
uniqueDates = set()
#read file contents into a set.
with open("date.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        uniqueDates.add(line.strip()) #strip off the line ending \n

#ensure what we're writing to the date file isn't a duplicate.
with open("date.txt", "a") as f:
    if("bs_obj()" not in uniqueDates):
        f.write("bs_obj")
```

You'll probably need to adjust the logic a bit to fit your needs, but, I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish?